# Is it possible to concurrently merge Source dataset to a partitioned delta table?

Tags: delta-lake

We are trying to achieve concurrent updates to a partioned delta table where the table is partitioned by fiscalmonth.
We are trying to merge from the source and want to run the upsert  in parallel.
We have a hash key as a joining column and the table is scd-2 .
The steps we have taken are.
For each partition we are selecting only the  fiscal month from the source.
1.We send the that dataframe to merge function and at the same time we are also add a where condition in the target so that only that partition is being selected.

2.Here is the merge statement with condtions.

Where source condition is

```
Target.fiscalmonthid = 351 
AND Target.HashKey = Source.HashKey 
AND Target.DataFiscalYearID = Source.DataFiscalYearID 
AND Target.IsCurrent = true 
For not matching by source we are using
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source  AND (
    Target.fiscalmonthid = 351 
    AND Target.DataFiscalYearID = 2023 
    AND (Target.IsCurrent = true OR Target.EffectiveEndDate >= '3000-12-31')

  
source_df_tmp=source_df (
   DeltaTable.forPath(self.spark, delta_table_path)
                                .alias("Target")\
                                .merge(
                                source=source_df_tmp.alias("Source"),
                                condition=merge_condition,
                            )  
                            .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
                            .whenNotMatchedBySourceUpdate(
                                condition=delete_condition,
                                set={
                            f"Target.{self.IS_CURRENT_COLUMN_NAME}": lit(False),
                            f"Target.{self.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE_COLUMN_NAME}": lit(currentDate),
                            f"Target.{self.LAST_REFRESHED_DATE_COLUMN_NAME}": lit(currentDate),
                            }
                            )
                                .execute()
                            )
```

Then we are parallelly running for each fiscal month .
But its failing with Files were added to partition concurrent update error.
Is it possible to concurrently merge at all ?

1.We have tried to add more conditions but looks like its not working.

Comment: Are you using s3? If so, you should see [this](https://delta.io/blog/2022-05-18-multi-cluster-writes-to-delta-lake-storage-in-s3/)